# Cannot set retailer location in a python script for browsing grocery stores using selenium in Ubuntu

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have been trying to update an old script that I used previously to set retailer locations on a grocery website and look at food prices. I cannot get it to reliably set the retailer location through selenium. I expect it to make a click, set the location, and then move on to look for foods etc. but it will inconsistently set the retailer location as intended. 9 times out of 10 it will click the button, a loading animation will take place, but no retailer change will occur.

I have tried this with multiple versions of the packages, multiple versions of ubuntu, and with a variety of options/preferences in both firefox (geckodriver) and chrome (chromedriver), and have had no sustained success. Some days the script will work for one run, I will make no changes, and it will never work again. I am running python 3.10.12, using the Selenium 4.15.2 package, in Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS as of my latest tests. I have been running this inside WSL2 on Windows 11, and testing on a server with Ubuntu with similar results. I have also been using selenium web driver manager rather than setting the location of drivers manually (old scripts did define Services manually).

Here is a sample attempt:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

## set Chrome options ##
options = Options()  # see imports at outset of script #
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
delay = 20

## Initiate the chrome driver  ##
Chrome_drive = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

print("New driver initiated")

wait = WebDriverWait(Chrome_drive, delay)

Chrome_drive.get("https://www.yourindependentgrocer.ca/store-locator")

sleep(2)

# select the location search bar

element = wait.until(
    EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(
        (By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".location-search__search__input")
    )
)

# as this will return a list, use the first instance and the click method

Chrome_drive.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element[0])

## input postal code and hit enter - see list argument ##

element[0].send_keys("Canada")

element[0].send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

sleep(30) # this was set to 30 just to check if the clicks were happening too fast #

# wait until the store selection button loads'

element = wait.until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable(
        (
            By.CSS_SELECTOR,
            "li.location-list__item:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > button",
        )
    )
)

print("selection made")

sleep(1)

# click the store selection button #
# this is completely inconsistent, sometimes it works, sometimes it fails to set the store despite the visualization for a click taking place #

Chrome_drive.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)

sleep(10)
# Quit
print("Quitting")
Chrome_drive.quit()
```

I expect this to click the store selection button and successfully set the store, but it rarely succeeds in this task. Most of the time it just causes a loading animation and then nothing changes on the site and the store location is not reset.

Further, I have tried opening up the site without coding clicks to follow and just used a mouse to click and it will not set the store unless I click it over and over again, and even then sometimes it fails.

I had more luck with chrome vs. firefox, but this issue is very similar in nature to one identified in October for geckodriver. Unfortunately, I have had very little success with chrome as well, and even that success is seemingly at random.
For other issue see [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/12881)